# SQL Result varies when changing "select" statement

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

So currently we are doing SQL @ our School and 
I was wondering about an suspicious result set when changing the select parameters.

So when I try this:

```
select p1.vorname, p1.Geburtstag, p2.vorname, p2.Geburtstag
from patienten as p1
inner join patienten as p2 
    on p1.Geburtstag = p2.Geburtstag AND p1.Nr != p2.Nr
order by p1.Geburtstag asc
```

Then I get 44 results. But when I try this:

```
select p1.vorname, p1.Geburtstag
    from patienten as p1
    inner join patienten as p2 
        on p1.Geburtstag = p2.Geburtstag AND p1.Nr != p2.Nr
    order by p1.Geburtstag asc
```

I get 1084 results, which represents all the patients...

I'm wondering why, cause all I did was changing the select statement...

I'm using XAMPP:

```
Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server-Typ: MariaDB
Server-Version: 10.1.8-MariaDB-log - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protokoll-Version: 10
Benutzer: root@localhost
Server-Zeichensatz: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Comment: Instead of saying that all you did was to change the select statement it would be more accurate and to the point to say that all you did was to change the list of selected fields.  Also, you should have avoided the different indentation to make it easier to see that the rest of the stuff are the same.

Comment: So: I don't believe that changing the list of selected fields yields different results.  Can you prove it?  Please provide an [MCVE].  That would mean `CREATE TABLE` statements, and `INSERT INTO` statements to populate the tables with sample data, so that executing the above two queries can be observed to yield the results that you claim that they yield.

Comment: There must be something else happening here. The number of rows a query returns is only then dependent from the columns selected when using `SELECT DISTINCT`. This is not the case in your query, so the number of returned rows must stay the same.

Comment: As @MikeNakis says, please try running both queries again.  Maybe you changed something else by accident, or maybe the data changed between executions?  How are you calling the queries and where are you seeing the results?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is information missing or OP made a mistake or data was deleted by another thread between the SELECT statements. This can not be reproduced.

Comment: Are the results repeatable? Can you execute the queries in a single transaction to prove the differences? I bet you ran the query with different on clause and then changed it or somebody replaced p1.Nr or p2.Nr with empty strings...

Answer (score 0):

First you indicated that this is MySQL which is known historically for not having stellar query optimization, so lets give it a clearer syntax to understand.  I suspect the != in the join is throwing MySQL off.  Change your query so you join on the common field and filter (ie where) on the != field:

```
select p1.vorname, p1.Geburtstag
    from patienten as p1
    inner join patienten as p2 
        on p1.Geburtstag = p2.Geburtstag 
    where p1.Nr != p2.Nr
    order by p1.Geburtstag asc
```

HTH,
Sean